# Badges Page HTML Showing

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

I can see the HTML is not embedded in Badges Page.

> [image]

Is it any issue in my browser or bug?

Comment: Yup! I didnt saw it.. even when I enter the question SO didnt shown related questions :(

Comment: Weird, someone cast a close vote and retracted it... ?

Comment: @Sha Why do you assume that? Because of the "possible duplicate..." comment? That's left for users that flag as a dupe, too.

Comment: @Cody nope, thought I saw a number next to the "duplicate of... " when closing but turns out the number was on the next step. (number of times others have selected this as the original) - can be pretty confusing!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd :) thanks for marking it as Duplicate :(

Comment: @TomPHP you're welcome welcome! ;)